# Invalid Syntax : facebook-sdk

Tags: python-3.x, urllib2

I am trying to import facebook pkg in python 
but its giving me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", 
 line 3326, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

 File "<ipython-input-6-56d9318bede4>", line 2, in <module>
  import facebook

 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\facebook.py", line 222
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my code

```
 import requests
 import facebook
```

I did try to uninstall and install the facebook pkg again but same issue occurred again.

I am using *Python 3.7.4*

Answer (score 1):

In [the code](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk/blob/v0.3.0/facebook.py) I can read this:

```
    #For Python 3 use this:
    #except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
```

But this code is in versions pre 1.0 which came in 2016. Try to use a newer version, or you could correct the code as suggested, that is comment the line and uncomment the upper line.

Comment: Thanks for reply , the new version worked. Looks like i have installed the old version when i used conda to install it. So this time i used  "pip install facebook-sdk" and it is now working fine.